# Parsing "ANY" object from/to JSON in *native* Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, reflection

I've read dozens of post (here and other places) asking for parsing from/to JSON and most people code their exclusive parsers for each class. The usual answer is to use GSON or other libraries but since android supports JSON natively I don't see the point of use third-party libraries.

So I made my own generic JSONParser using Android JDK libraries exclusively. It works fine for any class whose fields are: primitive types, strings, one-dimensional arrays, or other classes. The problem now is to handle arrays of more dimensions. I'm a noob using reflection and JSON, so maybe I misconceived something.

You have to specify the Class you want to convert the JSON string. Then it basically iterates through all the fields in the class and search for a field in JSON with the same name. **This works only for public methods** (it's not a hard problem for me now, but if someone have an idea to improve it I'll appreciate as well).

My problem comes when I have an array of arrays, I've tried several ways but I'm not able to find a solution to deal with n-dimensional arrays. This is my method for arrays, the "TO-DO" part is the one I don't have a clue for do it. I've tried using the commented line, but it fails. Possibly it's the same problem in both directions, but I'm concerned now in decoding the JSON.

```
    Everything solved!! Go to comments
```

I think it could be useful for more people, so I've uploaded the whole code here.  http://pastebin.com/X7CmaxNf

The method insertArrayFromJSON() is called from *public static Object populateObjectFromJSON(Class classname, JSONObject js) {}* line 65th.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer to the question, so you can accept it.

Comment: Thanks @graham-borland but: 
"Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 4 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead". So I let it in the question till I could answer myself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem by myself. I was stucked with this since yesterday because I was facing wrongly the array problem, but then I changed the method to attack it recursively in the right way. In the pastebin is the whole code ( I don't post here cause it's two hundred lines). Feel free for use it and if someone have some ideas to improve it, please tell me!.

http://pastebin.com/Jtf2SLDu

The main point was using Array.set(), Array.newInstance() and Array.get() methods properly. This is in lines 110-125 if someone wants to take a look.

For gain access to the protected&private methods I found the solution in this webiste. So now it works for any class with any public/protected/private field. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html

I've made in a way that you can set the privacy desired before parsing.